# Windows service with Nancy does not start host

Tags: c#, windows-services, nancy

I have developed a Windows Service whose task is actually to start a host with particular `url` and `port`. Below is what I have now.

**Program.cs**

```
static void Main()
{
    ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
    ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
    { 
         new WindowsDxService() 
    };
    ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
}
```

**ProjectInstaller.cs**

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class ProjectInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
{
    public ProjectInstaller()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**WindowsDxService.cs**

```
public partial class WindowsDxService : ServiceBase
{
    public WindowsDxService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        var url = "http://127.0.0.1:9000";
        using (var host = new NancyHost(new Uri(url)))
        {
            host.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Configuration on `serviceProcessInstaller1` and `serviceInstaller1` in `ProjectInstaller.cs [Design]` file.

```
serviceProcessInstaller1
     Account=LocalSystem
```

---

```
serviceInstaller1
     StartType=Automatic
```

**Library.cs**

```
public class Library : NancyModule
{
     public Library()
     {
         Get["/"] = parameters =>
         {
             return "Hello world";
         };
         Get["jsontest"] = parameters =>
         {
             var test = new
             {
                 Name = "Guruprasad Rao",
                 Twitter="@kshkrao3",
                 Occupation="Software Developer"
             };
             return Response.AsJson(test);
         };
     }
}
```

Basically I followed **[`this tutorial`](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnet/creating-microservices-using-nancyfx.html)** which actually shows how to do it with `Console application` which I succeeded though, but I wanted to have this as `Windows Service` which actually starts a `host` with specified `port` whenever the system starts. The service is started successfully and running but whenever I browse the `url` in the same system its not showing up the page, which means our basic **`This webpage is not available`** message. What else configuration I have to do so as to start the `host`? Hoping for a help.

Comment: Does `Host.Start` return? If it does you are disposing the host in the `OnStart` method. If it does not then your service won't start properly. Suggest you dispose when stopping the service.

Comment: @JackHughes Apologies, but I really started working with this `windows service` and `Nancy` today and I had very less knowledge on this. What If I have to keep this `host.Start()` going on even though the service stops.. The task of the service should be just start the `host`..

Comment: In `OnStartup` allocate the `Host` and call `Start` method. In `OnStop` dispose the host. The host would be a field inside the `WindowsDxService` class.

Comment: Hi Guruprasad Rao, Can u upload working code to GitHub for reference? It helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are disposing the host when you start your service. I would suggest something like this:

```
public partial class WindowsDxService : ServiceBase
{
    private Host host;

    public WindowsDxService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        this.host = new NancyHost(...)
        this.host.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        this.host.Stop();
        this.host.Dispose();
    }
}
```

You'd probably find it a lot easier to write the service if you used TopShelf library.

Comment: Perfect @Jack.. U nailed it.. :) Thank you.. I will try the same with `TopShelf` too.. :)